# Python: Socket: Handling TCP connections over a cell network

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, pexpect

I am doing some socket programming in python in which I develop a client TCP/IP socket to communicate with a slow embedded device. So sometimes, when the response is supposed to be only one package, it is broken in to two packages. My current solution to that is to `sleep()` the python program, waiting to make sure that all the data I need already arrived.

```
comSocket.send('\r')

sleep(1)

comSocket.send('\r')

comSocket.recv(128)

comSocket.send('\r\r')

comSocket.recv(256)



#sending I commands for data

comSocket.send('1I\r\r3I\r\r4I\r\r13I\r\r5I\r\r8I\r\r7I\r\r9I\r\r')

sleep(2)

#receiving data

rawData = comSocket.recv(512)

sleep(1.5)
```

I am wondering whether there is a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: can you be specific about the communication channel?  Is this an IP network, serial bus, or??

Comment: @Mike Pennington: It's TCP/IP socket over IP network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a single device, you should use a solution that handles the low-level `socket` interactions for you... python has several like [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect), [exscript](https://github.com/knipknap/exscript/wiki), or [`paramiko` (ssh only)](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/)...  if it is multiple devices and you need asynchronous communication, use @zeekay's answer (although async programming, particularly with twisted, is unpleasant if you're not already familiar with it).

I answered a question with the way you telnet and send a list of commands to a single device here...

[Catching a dying process in pexpect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602080/catching-a-dying-process-in-pexpect/5602629#5602629)

The answer above makes the code efficient, but is more challenging for a beginner to understand... the following code is simpler, it makes a telnet connection on TCP/23, waits for `*`, sends a command, and puts the response to the command in `mydata1`...

```
import pexpect as px
import sys

def send_this(child, retcode, COMMAND):
    if retcode == 2:
        child.sendline(COMMAND)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError, "Could not complete login, due to socket error"

def expect_this(child, EXPR, timeout = 10):
    return child.expect([px.TIMEOUT, px.EOF, EXPR], timeout = timeout)

HOST = '192.168.49.49'
CMD1 = '1I'
PROMPT = '\*'     #Note: you might not need the backslash
TIMEOUT = 10

child = px.spawn('telnet %s' % HOST)
retcode = expect_this(child, PROMPT)
send_this(child, retcode, CMD1)
retcode = expect_this(child, PROMPT)
mydata1 = child.before    # mydata has the output from CMD1
```

Regardless of the solution, the most important thing is tweaking your timeouts so you don't have to concern yourself with the long cell-network delays (which are sometimes over 5 seconds in my experience).

The other nasty dynamic in cellular communication is that many consumer devices *routinely* change their IP address when they are moving (due to their reliance on dhcp)... there isn't much TCP can do if this happens... if you don't have a static address the connection will drop when the device pulls a new ip address.

Comment: The device has static IP. I am reading `pexpect` right now and it seems pretty hard to digest since I never coded in python before. This is actually my 1st time ever :)

Comment: @Tanner, if this is your first endeavor coding in python, handling TCP sockets with the `socket` module isn't much more pleasant... I will post a simple script for you... are you using windows, osx, or linux?

Comment: @Mike Pennington: I am using Linux, python 2.7.2

Comment: @Mike Pennington: I am reading your script. For my device, it's much simpler: There's no authentication involed, I just need to establish the connection, send 3 different messages, receiving the corresponding responses, since delay is long and fluctuate, I had to `sleep()` my code. I am looking for a better way to handle the waiting to replace the `sleep()`.

Comment: @Tanner, `pexpect` is most efficient when you can send a command and then wait for a string that signifies that the device response is done... so, does the device use a prompt?  Also, is data security a concern?  No authentication or encryption is risky in many situations, these days...

Comment: Yes. The prompt would be `*`. There is nothing we can do about authentication since the device was built a long time ago.

Comment: @Tanner, I'm sorry to keep asking for clarification, but is that a literal `*`, or were you saying there is no prompt (thus use a wildcard)?  Also, if the device uses a literal `*` for the prompt, is that the last string a client sees after completing the TCP handshake with the cell device?

Comment: Oh sorry. That is a literal `*`, not a wildcard. And yes, after responding to a command, the device sends back result which ends with a `*`

Comment: @Tanner, no problem... I edited for what I think you need... let me know if this isn't doing the trick... if not, what problem do you have... note, you can insert `child.logfile = sys.stdout` if you need to see terminal logs of what this script does...

Answer (score 1):

Use a networking library like [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) or [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to `recv` inside a loop and will have to check if all message has been received with a protocol parser..

```
condition = True
while condition:
    rawData += sock.recv(512)
    # parse rawData to check if message is complete and if so you can set condition = False to break the loop
    if parser.is_complete(rawData):
        condition = False
```

Comment: What is the `library` or `module` to import for parser?

Comment: that was an ilustrative code.. does your device have a protocol? probarly you will have to implement or look for one implementation...